# I can't edit android emulator's host file

Tags: android

I try to edit android emulator's host file.I follow steps:

```
step1
adb root
step2
adb remount
step3
adb pull /system/etc/hosts .
```

then I add new line for customer host information,then I push hosts file,I get some errors:

```
   step4
   adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

error information:

```
adb: error: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

envirements information:

```
   osx ei capitan  
   android emulator: android 7.1.1  
   android studio: 2.2.2
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and made it work.

**Run the emulator:**

`emulator -avd <EMULATORNAME> -partition-size 512 -writable-system`

I believe that `-writable-system` param is the thing that fixed it for me.

**In another terminal/cmd prompt:**

`adb root`

`adb -s emulator-5554 remount`

`adb -s emulator-5554 pull /system/etc/hosts hosts`

Now, work your magic (add the IP to host file)

`adb -s emulator-5554 push hosts /system/etc/hosts`

**Additional info:**

- emulator-5554 is the device name, you can find yours with `adb devices`
- emulator program is located inside android-sdk/tools
- adb program is located in android-sdk/platform-tools

**Important update from comments:**

Please check the comment from steven to this post about running `adb reboot` before running `adb root`.
This might be important to being able to start the emulator from AVD manager.

Captain suggests to run `adb reboot` after pushing the host file to avoid blackscreen error.

Happy debugging :)

Comment: Now in ubuntu change to ./emulator -avd <EMULATORNAME> -partition-size 512 -writable-system

Comment: Just a warning that if you use this (working) method, you'll have to run this emulator with the writable-system param every time or the emulator screen will be black.

Comment: Please add the `adb reboot` to your answer! it is very important. Otherwise you could not start the emulator from avd manager any more!

Answer (score 3):

After pushing the hosts file run `adb reboot` and you will have no problem with the black screens anymore.

Comment: this answer is really important! You will get an `qemu-system-i368.exe has stopped working` crash in avd-manager if you don't reboot after starting in -writable-system mode. I would give you 10 upvotes if i could.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with the other solutions, so i tested a lot and now i decided to write another answer and i hope it is useful for others.

Here are my steps to success (Android Studio on win 10):

- Start Android Studio and open the AVD Manager and start your
  Emulator.
- Open a powershell and navigate to your android sdk/platform-tools/
- `.\adb.exe reboot -writable-system` (your emulator should reboot now)
- `.\adb.exe root`
- `.\adb.exe remount`
- `.\adb.exe pull /system/etc/hosts C:\Temp\hosts`
- Èdit your hosts file
- `.\adb.exe push C:\Temp\hosts /system/etc/hosts`
- `.\adb.exe unroot`
- Now you can open a browser in your emulator and open your custom domain to check if your hosts file has been changed.
- Click the close-icon of your emulator to force a shutdown with snapshot saving. You should see a "Saving state..." message.
- Now start your emulator again from AVD Manager. Your hosts file should persist. So check your domain again.

I had very strange issues with unstartable emulators after booting in writable-system mode, rooting and stopping emulator without doing the unroot. The problem is: whenever the snapshot fails the emulator will do a cold boot and your hosts file is gone. You need to repeat all the steps in that case.