# Android: edit /system/etc/host file

Tags: android, adb

I want to edit /system/etc/hosts int my Xiaomi 5 (rooted). I first pull `/syste/etc/hosts` and made some changes to it, I want to `push`it ,then I came across this problem

```
adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': couldn't create file: 
Read-only file system
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139087/i-cant-edit-android-emulators-host-file), but that didn't work out for me.

```
adb root   
adbd is already running as root

adb remount
remount of /system failed: Read-only file system
remount failed
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android), didn't work either.

it shows:

```
gemini:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
'/dev/block/dm-0' is read-only
gemini:/ # mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
```

Can anybody show me a way out, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,I finally find an answer on MIUI forum.

[What I found](http://www.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=8474497&highlight=%E4%BF%AE%E6%94%B9hosts%E6%96%87%E4%BB%B6) ,if you can read Chinese, open it directly;  if you can't I will explain the reason .

I can't edit the hosts file, because I didn't unlock `system`. MIUI has some kind of protect mechanism to prevent user delete important files after root.

So, download [this](https://github.com/kolibreath/MI-fast-boot), make sure your phone is in Fastboot mode. Connect it to your PC, and open a terminal where you put your `adb` files you just download.

```
adb root 

adb disable-verity
```

This will do it!