# How to edit hosts file on android emulator API 30 (Android R)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device, hosts-file

I'm trying to edit the hosts file on an android emulator with API 30 - Android R. I have completed remount successfully but it says

> Remount succeeded. Reboot device for changes to be effective

I am stuck on this step because no matter what way I reboot the emulator, it goes to

> Device offline

and shows just a black screen.
It gets restored only if I do a factory reset, but again the emulator file system becomes read-only and I cannot edit the hosts file.

The solutions I tried are as follows:

First step is common.
In adb command prompt:

```
cd [...\Android\android-sdk\emulator directory]
emulator -avd [EMULATORNAME] -writable-system
```

Then in system command prompt,

```
cd [...\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools directory]
```

**Method 1:**

```
adb root
adb remount
```

Here remount succeeds but I need to reboot the device.
All these ways of rebooting result in Device Offline state and black screen:

1. `adb reboot`
2. Manually restarting emulator by long pressing power button
3. In adb command prompt, pressing Ctrl + C to stop the emulator and starting again with:
   `emulator -avd [EMULATORNAME] -writable-system`

If I ignore the reboot and try to edit the hosts file pushing a new like this:

```
adb push hosts /system/etc
```

Then I get

> Error, cannot write to a read-only file system.

**Method 2:**

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /sys
```

This gives no error or success message. Then if I try any write operation such as:

```
adb push hosts /system/etc
```

or

```
cat hosts

10.1.3.5 bla.blabla.com >> hosts
```

Then it still says

> Error, cannot write to a read-only file system.

I have already tried these links and solutions with no success:

[How to edit /etc/hosts file in Android Studio emulator running in nougat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117715/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-android-studio-emulator-running-in-nougat)

[I can't edit android emulator's host file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139087/i-cant-edit-android-emulators-host-file/41144234)

[Android emulator-5554 offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152681/android-emulator-5554-offline)

[android emulator sdk 10 api 29 won't start after remount and reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867956/android-emulator-sdk-10-api-29-wont-start-after-remount-and-reboot)

Please help. Thanks in advance!